# compare 8bit value against 16bit value

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compare

I was wondering what happens when an 8bit value is compared against a 16bit value.

I'll try to explain the problem by a code example:

```
bool result;
unsigned char a_8bit = 0xcd;
unsigned short b_16bit = 0xabcd;
result = a_8bit < b_16bit;
```

Possible results can be:

- a_8bit is casted to unsigned short implicitly and compared to b_16bit as a 16bit value. Result is true
- b_16bit is casted to unsigned char implicitly and compared to a_8bit as an 8bit value. Result is false

Does anybody has a clue what the compiler will do with this piece of code? Sure, i can try it out, but are there different interpretations by different compilers of this code?

Comment: arithmetic conversion of both to int. and then casted to bool. but the size of int is implementation defined

Comment: @Koushik There's no cast to `bool`.  The results of `<` already have type `bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int. [§ 4.5]

So, compiler can promote both of them to `unsigned int` and then do the comparison.

Comment: is it not int since int can represent the values of both the operands?

Comment: Compiler can choose between `unsigned int` and `unsigned short` since both are able to represent two values, however the standard is more specific for `int`.

Comment: @MM. _IF_ the size of `int` is larger than the size of `short`.  But on a typical 32 (or 64) bit machine, yes.  They will both be converted to `int` before the comparison.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I was confused. Thanks for making it clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The first, although to be precise, both are converted to unsigned and then compared.

Answer (score 0):

Normal integer promotion rules apply, see for example: http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/