# Comparing 8 bits types of different signedness (int8_t, uint8_t): is result deterministic?

Tags: c++, c, gcc4.9

I run [this simple program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5d2876f81e6e938):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    uint8_t x = 100;
    int8_t y = -128;
    if (x < y) {
        std::cout << (int) x << " is less than " << (int) y << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << (int) y << " is less than " << (int) x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

With output, correctly:

```
-128 is less than 100
```

I was at first surprised to see no signedness warning was generated.
I was then surprised not to have a wrong conversion going on (-128 -> 255) and therefore not getting a wrong result.
Then I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20192160/2436175):

> <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int. [§ 4.5]

[Link to standard n2356](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/conv.html)
What does it mean "*Can* be converted"? Is it up to the compiler implementation if this conversion will happen and therefore if this expression will return a correct value?

The point is that the compiler *shall* search for a common type to which convert the 2 operands, but I don't find any obligation in the standard to *do its best* so that this common type is able to represent all possible values of both the 2 input types.

Note: I tagged also C as this case seems to be also applicable to it.
Related question: [Comparison signed and unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027305/comparison-signed-and-unsigned-char). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25918087/2436175).

Comment: Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera) and [these](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) rules

Comment: In C, both `x,y` are converted to `int` before the `<`  (Suggest 1 language tag)

Comment: @chux Sure, but based on which rule?

Comment: @CoryKramer The rules for integral promotion say "might", not "shall". Is there something I am missing?

Comment: C11 §6.3.1.1 2 "... If an `int` can represent all values of the original type ..., the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned
int`. ..."  If code used `uint16_t/int16_t`, then a difference occurs on 16-bit vs 32 `int`  platforms.

Comment: @Antonio C++11 §5/9 *Relational operators* "...if either operand is unsigned, the other **shall** be converted to unsigned"

Comment: My citation is from C11. Similar specs exist in C99 and earlier.  IAC `uint8_t /  int8_t` is only standard since C99.

Comment: @Antonio Same comment as chux. I cited the C++11 standard but these promotion rules have existed in previous versions.

Comment: @chux 6.4.1.1.2 starts by saying "the following *may* be used", so again the obligation is missing.

Comment: @CoryKramer I cannot find your citation in Paragraph 5.9 of C++11 ([document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/2436175)). Besides, the text you reported would say that the signed type would have to be converted to unsigned, which was exactly my point in the question (-128 -> 255).

Comment: I think you mean "defined", not "deterministic".

Comment: C11 §6.3.1.1 2 The first paragraph has the "The following _may_ be used...."  and subsequent text of that paragraph is dependent on the "_may_".  "If an `int` can represent all values..." is a second paragraph and stands on its own and is part of the larger _usual arithmetic conversions_.

Comment: @smead No, I really meant "deterministic", in the sense of (compiler's) "implementation defined". Not "undefined" in the sense that your machine can explode :) See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132574/does-undefined-behavior-really-permit-anything-to-happen) for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the result is deterministic, not (compiler's) implementation defined. Here follows the motivation for C++11 (it should be possible to do the same for other), following the document [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (link suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents/4653479#4653479))

It's necessary to combine all of the following:

> 5.9 Relational operators
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. The *usual arithmetic conversions* are performed on operands of arithmetic or enumeration type.

To find the *usual arithmetic conversion* we need to go to the incipit of Chapter 5, paragraph 9:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called **the usual arithmetic conversions**, which are defined as follows:
>
> - [...] (Enumeration and floating point types)
> - Otherwise, the **integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both**
>     **operands**.[59] Then the following rules shall be applied to the *promoted*
>     operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.
>   - [...]

So, integral promotion, citing from 4.5:

> A prvalue of an integer type *other than* bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion
>   rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned
>   int.

So:
We have a relational operator, the usual arithmetic conversions will be used. These *oblige* to apply integral promotion. An integral promotion for `uint8_t` and `int8_t` is possible to `int`, so it is *obligatorily* applied.

**Therefore the comparison between a `uint8_t` and `int8_t` is transformed by the compiler into a comparison between 2 `int`. There is no undeterministic behaviour.**

There was a similar Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23635240/2436175) (about `short` type though), which led me to the right path.

**Note the following contradiction though**: Relational operators return a boolean value (5.9.1), yet they use the usual arithmetic conversions which is used to obtain 2 operands of the same type. But, here lays the problem, the definition of usual arithmetic conversion says that the common type will be also the type of the result, which isn't the case for relational operators!!

The contradiction is not there for C11, where the result returned by relational operators is indeed an `int`. (Thanks chux)

Comment: Why do you keep mentioning undefined behaviour. Even if there were no integer promotion there would still not be undefined behaviour, just "wrong result" as you put it

Comment: Re. the last paragraph, " The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result."  refers to the previous sentence "Many binary operators" -- note "Many", not "All"

Comment: "Relational operators return a boolean value" is where C/C++ part company.  In C, they return an `int`.

Comment: @M.M In the answer I had used "undefined" in place of "undeterministic" (implementation defined), corrected it now. If the phrase says "Many binary operators [...] cause conversions [...]". If something cause conversions, like the relational operators, than all that follows in the paragraph applies, including "which is also the type of the result". Also seen the other way around: relational operators require (as many other binary operators) the usual arithmetic conversions, which say that the type it converts to is also the type of the result. The C++11 standard is definitely in contradiction.

Comment: The _contradiction_ your describe is misplaced.  The result of the _arithmetic conversion_ is 2 values of the common type.  The common type version of both arguments are then applied to the relationship operator which results in `int/bool` (C/C++).

Comment: @chux No. Just before it says "***Many binary operators*** *that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and* ***yield result types*** *in a similar way.*" So the phrase after is clearly referring to the result type of the binary operator.

Comment: There is no contradiction as that says "Many binary operators" and not "All binary operators" so it need not apply to relational operators.

Comment: @chux I have already answered this point raised by M.M. [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856970/comparing-8-bits-types-of-different-signedness-int8-t-uint8-t-is-result-dete/39863945?noredirect=1#comment67024254_39863945).